# Mouse right click option using eventFilter in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have QGraphicsView, which has many QGraphicsItem. I am trying to create a right click menu on these QGraphicsItem. Right click menu has multiple options. But only 1st option works. It means, if I click on 2nd option, it does not work. If I change the sequence ( means 1st one will go to 2nd position, and 2nd one will come to 1st position ) then still 2nd one will not work.

```
bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
  switch(event->type())
  {
    case QEvent::ContextMenu:
    {
        foreach(QGraphicsItem* pItem, _scene->items())
        {
            if(pItem->isUnderMouse())
            {     
               QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*> (event);
               menu = new QMenu(this);    
               myMenu = menu->addMenu("Copy");
               myMenu ->addAction(Name);
               myMenu ->addAction(Address);
               if(Name == menu->exec(mouseEvent->globalPos()))
               {
                   // logic
               }
               if(Address == menu->exec(mouseEvent->globalPos()))
               {
                   // logic
               }
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Always works only 1st mouse right click option. Why is so ?

Comment: Why do you call exec() twice? exec() returns the selected action so check this with your two possible values instead calling exec() a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do something like this is to override the `QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent()` or `QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent()` function of your item class.

This way, you won't have to do anything (no looping, etc...), it is already handled by the event loop.

Here you can find a simple example:

```
void MyItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        QMenu my_menu;

        // Build your QMenu the way you want
        my_menu.addAction(my_first_action);
        my_menu.addAction(my_second_action);
        //...

        my_menu.exec(event->globalPos());
    }
}
```

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20all%20signals%20are%20emitted%20as%20usual.%20If%20you%20connect%20a%20QAction%20to%20a%20slot%20and%20call%20the%20menu%27s%20exec()%2C%20you%20get%20the%20result%20both%20via%20the%20signal%2Dslot%20connection%20and%20in%20the%20return%20value%20of%20exec().):

> Note that all signals are emitted as usual. If you connect a QAction to a slot and call the menu's exec(), you get the result both via the signal-slot connection and in the return value of exec().

You just need to `QObject::connect()` the `QAction`s you added to the context menu to the proper slots (here goes the "logic") and the job is done.

---

If you prefer to check the returned value by yourself, you just have to get the returned `QAction*` once and for all (only one call to `QMenu::exec()`) and branch on it.

For example:

```
void MyItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        QMenu my_menu;

        // Build your QMenu the way you want
        my_menu.addAction(my_first_action);
        my_menu.addAction(my_second_action);
        //...

        QAction * triggered = my_menu.exec(event->globalPos());
        if(triggered == my_first_action)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else if(triggered == my_second_action)
        {
            // Do some other thing
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

I would personnally prefer to stick with the signal-slot connections instead that manually handling the returned value, especially since each `QAction` is most likely to be already connected to its corresponding slot.